# Flux File upload validation - file type

Tags: file-upload, spring-webflux, reactive

I am new to reactive programming. I am using flux for file upload.  I need to make sure that all the files uploaded are of a specific type. If not I need to fail the request.

File.flatmap(input-> validate file())
.flatMAp(output->uploadtoazur())

My problem is when the second file is unacceptable type the first file has been processed. I want validateFile to scan all file and then do processing further

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you want to process all the files at a time, not one-by-one, you should first collect them, since you're dealing with `Flux`. So, you can achieve it with `collectList()` on your `Flux`

And then, having `List` of your files, you can validate and process them. Here is an example of making your validation with [handle()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#handle-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

On your `Flux` of files:

```
.collectList() // collect all files to List
.handle((files, sink) -> {
    // validate all your files here, for example, using regular Stream API with allMatch()
    ...
    if (allValid) {
        // return these files if all files are valid
        sink.next(files);
    } else {
        // throw Exception if some files are not valid
        sink.error(new Exception("Some files are not valid"));
    }
})
...
// further processing
```

This is one of the many possible ideas how to achieve what you want.

P.S. Actually you should have provided more code and format it properly.